# Input Method Dialog

Tags: android, methods, input

is there any way to show the Input Method selection dialog from the source code?

Comment: This is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: kgiannakakis, you didn't understand me, I don't want to show or hide the input method (Keyboard or what ever is selected by the user) I'm seeking for a way to show the standar android Dialog window where the user can select (switch) between different input methods installed on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

From inside an Activity:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Or if you have a Context object (or getContext() (a subclassed view)):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showInputMethodPicker();
```